# MySQL Trigger to Combine Two Events

Tags: mysql, events, triggers

**Hello All,**

I am not very experienced with MySQL triggers, only done basic things such as inserting of timestamps when a new record is inserted. With that in mind, I am seeking for some help on how to solve the following problem. Any help will be much appreciated.

I collect raw events into a table. These events are written when a tag changes state, i.e. on or off. Please see table below for an example;

```
events_raw

+----+----------+-----+-------+---------------------+
| id | location | tag | state | time                |
+----+----------+-----+-------+---------------------+
| 1  | 14       | 23  | ON    | 2013-06-07 07:59:52 |
| 2  | 14       | 24  | ON    | 2013-06-07 08:13:03 |
| 3  | 14       | 17  | ON    | 2013-06-07 08:21:21 |
| 4  | 14       | 23  | OFF   | 2013-06-07 08:25:15 |
| 5  | 14       | 6   | ON    | 2013-06-07 09:30:55 |
| 6  | 14       | 24  | OFF   | 2013-06-07 09:58:42 |
| 7  | 14       | 23  | ON    | 2013-06-07 09:58:53 |
+----+----------+-----+-------+---------------------+
```

What I would like to achieve is a second table like the example below. When records are inserted into events_raw, process them into another table that has one record containing the time that tag was on and when it changed to off. Once processed I would like to remove the records from alarm_data.

```
events_processed

+----+----------+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | location | tag | time_start          | time_finish         |
+----+----------+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 14       | 23  | 2013-06-07 07:59:52 | 2013-06-07 08:25:15 |
| 2  | 14       | 24  | 2013-06-07 08:13:03 | 2013-06-07 09:58:42 |
+----+----------+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I'm really sorry if my explanation is poor. I am really stuck on this, if you need more info to go on please say.

Again, thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a unique key in  Location + Tag columns .. then you can write a trigger in events_row as

```
CREATE TRIGGER TGR_ROW_AI AFTER INSERT ON event_Row FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    INSERT INTO events_processed (location,tag,time_start) 
    VALUES (New.Location,New.tag,new.time) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time_finish =new.time ;
END;
```

I Assume the ID column is an autoIncrement column.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I am having issues with line 5 of your answer, MySQL doesn't like that new.time at the end or something? I created a unique key called event_key and the ID columns auto increment. Thanks again.

Comment: please post the actual error message that you are getting ... its working fine for me. see this SQLfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74299/1

Comment: Hello, thank you. I managed to get the trigger to work like this: http://pastebin.com/CZAhbD6w Although this works, the next time a tag comes on/off it doesn't create a new record in events_processed, it overwrites the finished column for the existing/first record with the same tag.

Comment: I guess this is not possible with the information I have available. I will try introduce a new column that contains a unique id for each event occurrence and use your answer above to create a unique key based on location,tag,generated id. Thank you.